# SpringBoot JPA data access App doesn't recognise Repository type

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've written a basic SpringBoot web app using Java 8 to read tuples from a table called Tmsdata.

SyncApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SyncApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SyncApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

SyncController.java:

```
@Controller
public class SyncController {

  @Autowired
  private TmsdataService tmsdataService;


  @GetMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String default() {

    List<Tmsdata> a = tmsdataService.findAll();

    return "{ message: 'OK', count: " + a.size() + " }";
  }

}
```

TmsdataRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface TmsdataRepository extends JpaRepository<Tmsdata, Long> {
    // Define custom query methods if needed

}
```

TmsdataService:

```
@Service
public class TmsdataService {

  @Autowired
  private TmsdataRepository tmsdataRepository;

  public List<Tmsdata> findAll() {

    List<Tmsdata> a = tmsdataRepository.findAll();

    return a;
  }

}
```

Tmsdata.java:

```
public class Tmsdata {
  @Id
  private Long record_id;
}
```

When I compile the project there are no issues, but when I do `mvn spring-boot:run` I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field tmsdataRepository in com.company.sync.TmsdataService required a bean of type 'com.company.sync.TmsdataRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.sync.TmsdataRepository' in your configuration.
```

As you can see I already have defined the JPA Repository with that name.  What else could be going on here?

Comment: Please include the imports and packages in your sources, as well specify which Spring Boot version you are using (or rather post your dependencies).

Comment: Did you miss @Entity annotation in Tmsdata.java by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add annotation `@Entity` to your entity class

Try the following :

```java
@Entity
public class Tmsdata {
  @Id
  private Long record_id;
}
```

If you want to add a name for the table add `@Table` annotation like so:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "your-table-name")
public class Tmsdata {
  @Id
  private Long record_id;
}
```